# Python sequential search

Tags: python

I found this code (modified it) and trying to understand the code.
I've understand part of it, but I'm still a little confused about the code.

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]

cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
ketemu = False
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if cari == a[i]:
        ketemu = True

if ketemu:
  print("Value: ", cari, "ada")
else:
  print("Value: ", cari, "not found")
```

I'm a little bit confused on the part
Ketemu = False, and ketemu = True.
How come this code can shows if inputed value is exist at a variable or not.

Comment: do you understand `if cari == a[i]`? (also, this is very untypical Python code, the normal way of checking whether `cari` is in `a` would simply be `ketemu = cari in a`, no need for a `for` loop at all.

Comment: Walk through the code, step by step, if you enter an input that is in `a` (for example, `9`). Then walk through the code, step by step, if you enter an input that isn't in `a` (e.g. `4`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tl;dr - The code assumes that cari is not in the list until proven otherwise.*

Let's go step-by-step through this code and see if we can analyze what is happening.

Step 1: Initialization

```
a = [2,5,7,9,11]

cari = int(input("Input the value : "))
ketemu = False
```

This is the part of the code where initial values are set. First, the list we want to check to see if cari is in is defined. Second, we take in a value for cari. Finally, we set a **default** value for ketemu. This final initialization is crucial for understanding the code. ketemu is **False** until proven otherwise, and we will see why that's important when looping through the a values.

Step 2: Check for cari

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if cari == a[i]:
        ketemu = True
```

In this step, we are checking to see if cari is in the list a, so we cycle through each of the elements in the list. We are trying to prove whether cari is in the list, and if it is, ketemu is set to **True**. The reason that ketemu is originally set to False and changed to True lets us know for certain whether cari is in a.

Let's run through an example [cari in the list]:

```
let cari be 7, ketemu be False
loop through each element of the list [2,5,7,9,11]
is cari == 2? No --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 5? No --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 7? Yes --> ketemu is changed to True
is cari == 9? No --> ketemu remains True and is not replaced with False
is cari == 11? No --> ketemu remains True and is not replaced with False
```

Let's run through an second example [cari not in the list]:

```
let cari be 4, ketemu be False
loop through each element of the list [2,5,7,9,11]
is cari == 2? No --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 5? No --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 7? Yes --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 9? No --> ketemu remains False
is cari == 11? No --> ketemu remains False
```

These examples reveal something to us. If cari is in the list, this logic structure allows us to set ketemu to True **without replacing** it with False. If cari is not in the list, this means that ketemu can remain False without any extra work.

Step 3: Outputting results

```
if ketemu:
   print("Value: ", cari, "ada")
else:
  print("Value: ", cari, "not found")
```

At this step, we want to tell the user whether we have found cari in list a. Let's use the previous examples to find out what happens here. It's important to note that in Python the following two statements have the same meaning.

```
if ketemu:
if ketemu == True:
```

Example 1: cari is in the list

In this example, cari was set to 7, and ketemu was set to True.

```
is ketemu True? Yes --> prints "Value: 7 ada"
```

Example 2: cari is not in the list

In this example, cari was set to 4, and ketemu remained False.

```
is ketemu True? No, go to else state --> prints "Value: 4 not found"
```

From this step-by-step analysis, we can see the logic behind this snippet of code. If cari is found in the list, ketemu is set to True and a positive response is printed out. If cari is not found in the list, ketemu remains the default value False and a negative response is printed out.

*Bonus Section: How To Improve This Code*

In Python, you can ask if a variable is in a list directly using the "in" operator. This is how you would improve step 2 with this trick:

```
ketemu = cari in a
```

If cari is in the list a, ketemu will be set to True. If it isn't then ketemu will be set to False. This can be handy trick if you have a large list as looping can be time consuming.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it really really helps me a lot. After i read your explanation, i tried using the "in" thing in python. Here is my result if you have any comment please tell me how to improve my code

Answer (score 1):

```
My_favourite_number = [1,7,9,10]

input_user= int(input("Input the value : "))
ketemu = input_user in My_favourite_number

if input_user == ketemu:
    print("Yes, number" , input_user, "is my favourite number")
else :
    print("No," , input_user, "is not my favourite number")
```

Comment: This will not work. Assume that input_user == 7, which will make ketemu == True. The if statement is then asking "is 7 == True" and the answer is no. Rather, you want the if statment to read "if ketemu". See Step 3 in my answer if you're confused about how that works.